# Property 'add' does not exist on type 'typeof math'

Tags: typescript

this is my code

```js
export class math {
    constructor(number1: number, number2: number):number {
        this.num = number1;
        this.num2 = number2;
    }
     add() {
        return this.num + this.num2
    }
}
```

when i run

```js
console.log(math.add(4, 2)) //or any other number
```

i get the error..

here is my tsconfig.json

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "lib": ["ESNext", "dom", "es6"],
        "module": "commonjs",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "target": "ESNext",
        "outDir": "dist",
        "sourceMap": false,
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "importHelpers": true
    },
    "exclude": ["./node_modules"]
}
```

I have tried making it an "any" type it didnt work, i tried alot of other things and it didnt work..

Comment: Have you ever learned Object orient programming before learning typescript?

Comment: It has to be a static method if you want to call it like that.

Answer (score 1):

```
class math {
     x: number;
     y: number;
    constructor(x = 0, y = 0) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }


    add() {
         console.log(this.x+this.y)
    }
}

let calculate = new math(1,2)

calculate.add()
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a class to create methods on an object:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgQygCxgXhgbwLACgYwIAmRMAFGAIwBcMYArnAEYCmATgDR0BMtDz7AJR9GrNljwECbFlHpswdSjADUPANySYAXzzbNuPKEiwIjdPCTIAdMSJluXAMyCDxiCAA2La55ABzMjM4VxgAejCYAFY8IA)

```ts
const math = {
  add (n1: number, n2: number): number {
    return n1 + n2;
  }
};

const sum = math.add(2, 3);
console.log(sum); // 5
```